# Are TO220 and DO201 diodes interchangeable?

Tags: diodes

Schottky diodes seem to come in two packages, TO220 and DO201. DO201 is a common 2-pin that I am used to. But they don't seem to make them for high currents and low voltages, e.g. 30A/35V. Instead I see a lot of TO220 diodes for sale for such currents. I wonder if I can replace a DO201 diode with a TO220 diode and just connect two out of three pins and not change anything else in the schematic? The TO220 ones have higher VRRM, about 100V instead of 35V, but I'm guessing it doesn't matter as long as it is higher. It is for a voltage regulator on the power supply so I am trying to be careful and not to blow anything up.

Comment: If it has the same electrical specification, then basically yes!
Now it doesn't so no it does not.
The TO220 also has a larger heatsink in the body so it can handle more power.

Comment: The primary difference of the packages is heat dissipation.  Same die in a TO220 can handle more heat than one in a DO201.     You can use a TO220 almost surely (but you didn't post part numbers, so that's a "general" statement).    Note the metal tab in TO220's is often electrically "live"  i.e. it's connected to one of the pins.